# how to set the font size of textview for listview in file java?

Tags: android, android-listview

I wonder how to set the font size listview in java..
does anyone want to help?

here is my code for listview :

```
    Categories weather_data[] = new Categories[]
            {
                new Categories(R.drawable.dokter, "Cardiology"),
                new Categories(R.drawable.dokter, "Dentistry"),
                new Categories(R.drawable.dokter, "Dermatology and Venereology"),
                new Categories(R.drawable.dokter, "Disgetive Surgery"),
                new Categories(R.drawable.dokter, "ENT")
            };

    CategoriesAdapter adapter = new CategoriesAdapter(this,R.layout.listcategoriesitem, weather_data);

    lvcategories = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvcategories);

   lvcategories.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bawah2);

    lvcategories.setAdapter(adapter);
```

thx you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom adapter:

```
private class CategoriesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Categories> {

        public CategoriesAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Categories> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            Categories o = this.getItem(position);
            if (o != null) {
                TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryName);
                if (tt != null) {
                    tt.setText(o.getName());
                    tt.setTypeface(typeface);
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```